# GRUB gone. Can't log back into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have 2 SSD in my PC. One has Windows 10, the other Ubuntu.

I just installed 19.10 in my "Ubuntu SSD", and now when the PC starts, GRUB is completely gone. **I have no way to log back into Windows.**

These are my partitions for each disk:

[image]

[image]

What did go wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't appear GRUB when you press shift key during boot?

Comment: I honestly do not know much about how what GPT, MBR, Fast Boot or Secure Boot. I will look into the Bios... brb

Comment: I dont think there is any Fast Boot or Secure Boot installed...

Comment: /dev/sda is where Ubuntu was installed.  /dev/sdb is where Windows was installed.  Both use old school Master Boot Record (MBR) formatting, but /dev/sda1 is an EFI partition; most interesting.

Comment: Try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) first and then post the log files if it doesn't work.